# Need to get variable value from if statement

Tags: linux

I'm trying to make monitoring of backup running on server. There might be a better way of doing this, but I would like to fix my way as well.

I've tried multiple things and ended up here, the `$N` variable I made doesn't transfer out of `if` statement, I need to find on which line the `XXX` backup is and then show previous 7 lines, I know there is such a thing as `grep -C` or `-B -A` but I need this to work on systems which does not have `grep -ABC`.

```
BACKUP COMMAND | head -$(if [[ $(BACKUP COMMAND | grep -n XXX | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}' | cut -f 1 -d ':' | awk '{$N=$1; print $N}') ]];then echo $N; else echo 0;fi ) | tail -7
```

Result of the `if` statement should be number of line where the `"XXX"`.

My problem is getting that number from `if` statement to the rest of the command.

Comment: Wow, I don't think I've ever seen a quite so inefficient series of pipelines that spawns a minimum of 8-subshells including calling `awk` twice. If you post a few lines of your log file and further explain what it is you need out of them (other than just `XXX`) I'm sure we can find something that will work for you a bit better.

Comment: Hello, I'm not really that skilled with linux so i don't know where to find such log. XXX stands for backup name in this case, its 3 letter / number name for example XXX T3F or w/e made of 3 capital letters or numbers. My problem is getting Number that is stored in $N out of "IF" so i can use it as head -$N, also originaly there was only 1 awk so i tought it has problem with ":" and fails on that step but I was wrong and issue is (at least thats what i think now) that variables reset for each command.

Comment: To describe it step by step, it uses the backup command to get all backups running, then it find particular one in this case XXX, takes it's line number which looks like 33: for example, cuts the ":" away so it can be used as number, and then does the backup command again with number it got before as head -number and tails 7 of that output to show all the relevant information related to that backup.